# SHA256Digest is returning a weird hash

Tags: java, blackberry, sha256

In a **BlackBerry** application, I am using this code in order to get a hash from a password:

```
        SHA256Digest sha256d = new SHA256Digest();
        byte[] passwordData = null;

        try {
            passwordData = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        DigestOutputStream outputStream = new DigestOutputStream(sha256d, null);
        try {
            outputStream.write(passwordData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] hashedValue = sha256d.getDigest();
        tempSHA256Password = new String(hashedValue);
        System.out.println(tempSHA256Password);
```

At the end of this code block, the `tempSHA256Password` is going to be something that looks like this: `ëÇ#ÎiGê8óq =ßÝ÷<rê¨_FR»ã` ... so in no way what I am expecting. I am expecting a string that looks like this: `ebc723ce6947ea38f371a03d0cdfddf73c840f7215eaa85f031446529bbb16e3`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't print directly a binary value:

```
tempSHA256Password = new String(hashedValue);
System.out.println(tempSHA256Password);
```

So if you want to convert it to hex you can use this method :

```
static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";
public static String getHex( byte [] raw ) {
  if ( raw == null ) {
    return null;
  }
  final StringBuffer hex = new StringBuffer( 2 * raw.length );
  for ( final byte b : raw ) {
    hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
     .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
  }
  return hex.toString();
}
```

This method comme from [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0596.html), you have also other example if interested.

Comment: I ended up using [this](http://goo.gl/0Crv2) eventually. It's similar to your solution.

Comment: Indeed it's exactly the same thing, your link provide more comments btw thanks!

Comment: If you do want to make your answer appropriate for BlackBerry OS, you should replace `StringBuilder` with `StringBuffer` btw. Also, you can remove the Base64 encoding part, that's not what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

Insted of `tempSHA256Password = new String(hashedValue);`
try this code:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
for(byte b : hashedValue)
{
    buffer.append(String.format("%02x",b<0 ? b+256 : b));
}
tempSHA256Password = buffer.toString();
```

Comment: Can you give me an explanation why you have used `b<0 ? b+256 : b`? Why/How can `b` be smaller than 0? Why do we add 256 to it? Other than that, thanks! This solution works.

Comment: Bytes in Java are always signed, but in a hash value the byte 0xff is meant to be 255, not -1. When (implicitly) casting the byte to an int this code interpreters the bytes value as if it is unsigned.

Comment: Actually, seems like this code is leaving out a couple of 0 (zero). For example, take the string `tobehashed`. The actual end hex value should be `a4ed677da365940d77fff663b7c5e27d9e166514c681df2fa2024089e0bfc422`, but this code is returning `a4ed677da36594d77fff663b7c5e27d9e166514c681df2fa224089e0bfc422` leaving out a couple of zero's

Comment: This can easily be fixed by using `buffer.append(String.format("%02x",b<0 ? b+256 : b));` if I remember the format string correctly.

Comment: Yep, thanks for the tip. That should work...however, not on a BlackBerry, as BlackBerry's don't have the String.format method. I'll have to figure out a way to do that with MessageFormat.format I guess...

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
tempSHA256Password = new String(hashedValue);
```

That tries to create a string from arbitrary binary data as if it were text encoding with the platform default encoding. It sounds like you're looking for hex instead. There are loads of different hex encoding utility libraries in Java - you might want to look at [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) for example.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for the hex string. However, I can't import the Apache library into a BlackBerry project. Seems like I can only use j2me libraries on BB.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is binary form of hash. You must convert it to hex.